# Slide Column over, not move whole element JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to figure out how to get left column to go over the top as an overlay... not move the whole table.
I've seen examples of where it overlays the whole page, but i just need it to overlay in the nested section, not the whole page.

Im not exactly sure what you call it when the left column slides over the top of the inner element, but ive seen examples of it sliding over the the whole page, i just need it to slide over the top of the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".toggle-sidebar").click(function () {
$("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapsed");
$("#content").toggleClass("col-md-12 col-md-9");

return false;
});
});
</script>
<style>
html,
body {
height: 100%;
}
.jumbotron {
margin-top: 30px;
}
#content,
#sidebar {
min-height: 500px;
}
#row-main {
overflow-x: hidden; /* necessary to hide collapsed sidebar */
}
#content {
background-color: lightyellow;

-webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: width 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: width 0.3s ease;
transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
#content .btn-group {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.col-md-9 .width-12,
.col-md-12 .width-9 {
display: none; /* just hiding labels for demo purposes */
}
#sidebar {
background-color: lightgrey;

-webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: margin 0.3s ease;
transition: margin 0.3s ease;
}
.collapsed {
display: none; /* hide it for small displays */
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.collapsed {
display: block;
margin-left: -25%; /* same width as sidebar */
}
}

#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 50%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; font-size: 1.4em; height: 15px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.25em; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="row-main">
<div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar">
side area
</div>
<div class="col-md-9" id="content">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Controls">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default toggle-sidebar">Toggle sidebar</button>
</div>
<pre>Inner</pre>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/nrqpay4k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sidebar to go on top of the rest of the content you have to make its `position: absolute`.

You also should take it out of the table.

This is what you need:

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.collapsed {
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

I also changed a little bit of the html to take the sidebar out of the row element.

**____ update - close button added _____**

To add a close button add the following html inside the sidebar container:

```
 <button id="closeSidebar">x</button>
```

The css is the following:

```
#closeSidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And finally the Javascript is the following:

```
  $("#closeSidebar").click(function() {
    $("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapsed");
    return false;
  });
```

See if this is what you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/wnpv2got/2/

Comment: Diogo Peres that worked great, however when the side bar goes over the button i cant close it :)
Is there a way to add something to the popout box that lets me close it with the same slide effect out?

Comment: @JoeFox You can change the toggle button to the right side. I have put the button on the right side on the fiddle that I posted.

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark with a checkmark so others know this question it's solved.

Comment: Can an <- arrow or X be on the pop up that closes it? not sure how to put that in the uppoer right of that pop out, thank you for all the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I've edit the response to include a close button. See the fiddle bellow it.

Comment: that worked great, 1 last thing, how do i control the closing so it has a smooth animation, i know its through css just not sure how to make it smooth like when you click to show it, thank you so much!